# Circular inclusion with function inside namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files, circular-dependency, friend-function

I'm starting to learn C++ and recently encountered a problem with circular dependency of two headers.

I've already tried forward declaring the Class and namespace, also played around with it in a seperate project but didn't find any solution. Whatever I do the function doesn't get access to the class private members.

Here i simplified the problem a little bit.

---

#### A.h

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"

class Player {
private:
    int m_number;
public:
    friend void Byte::getDataChunk(Player& p);
};
```

---

#### B.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

#include "A.h"

class Player;

namespace Byte {
    void doOtherStuff() {
        //other Stuff
    }

    void getDataChunk(Player& p) {
        std::cout << p.m_number;
        doOtherStuff();
    }
}
```

---

I would really like to keep the class and namespace in seperate files, but I don't see any way of doing it. 
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `A.h` to include a forward declaration of `getDataChunk()` in namespace `Byte`:

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"

class Player;

namespace Byte {
    void getDataChunk(Player& p);
}

class Player {
private:
    int m_number;
public:
    friend void Byte::getDataChunk(Player& p);
};
```

Please note also that including function definitions in header files (i.e. `getDataChunk()` in `B.h`) is going to cause you headaches.

Comment: It worked, except that `std::cout << p.m_number;` threw an error that i used an undefined Type `Player`. When i moved that function declaration into a seperate `B.cpp` file it worked